# PHP function() return not working after sending email via outlook

Tags: php

Help newbie here, `return $id` is not working after sending email via outlook. Any tips?

```
    function save_book(){
    extract($_POST);
    $data = " booked_cid = '$cid' ";
    $data .= ", name = '$name' ";
    $data .= ", emp_id = '$emp_id' ";
    $data .= ", emp_email = '$emp_email' ";
    $data .= ", reservation_date = '$res_date' ";
    $data .= ", schedule_id = '$sched' ";
    $data .= ", workstations = '$workstations' ";
            
    $save = $this->db->query("INSERT INTO checked set ".$data);
    $id=$this->db->insert_id;

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['emp_email'];
    $res = $_POST['res_date'];
    $sched = $_POST['sched'];
    $cat = $_POST['cid'];
    $worksta = $_POST['workstations'];
    
    if($save){
                $subject="Reservation System Confirmation";        
                $message="Confirmation of your Reservation on $sched at $cat, $worksta ";        
                $to="$email";      
                com_load_typelib("outlook.application"); 

                if (!defined("olMailItem")) {define("olMailItem",0);}

                $outlook_Obj = new COM("outlook.application") or die("Unable to start Outlook");    
                echo "Loaded MS Outlook, version {$outlook_Obj->Version}\n";        
                $oMsg = $outlook_Obj->CreateItem(olMailItem);        
                $oMsg->Recipients->Add($to);
                $oMsg->Subject=$subject;        
                $oMsg->Body=$message;        
                $oMsg->Save();
                $oMsg->Send();      
    return $id;
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess, there is some error while saving your data on the DB, if it works fine then, check the credentials you are using to send the email, also the way it saves the data is very unsecured, you should filter the post data, and add validations.

Comment: Thank you for your response, the insert command actually goes through, my problem however is `return $id;` is not working but when I remove the codes from: `$subject="Reservation System Confirmation";`  to  `$oMsg->Send(); ` , it works just fine